# Micro SD card with adaptor in Ubuntu 12.04 only mount read-only

Tags: sd-card

I am trying to mount a microSD card with adaptor in Ubuntu 12.04 but it will only mount if I lock the adaptor before putting the card in and thus get a read only mounted card.

If I do not lock the adaptor before I cannot see the card. In Windows I do not have any problem, the card will mount read/write without any problem.

Any idea what to do in order to get it working read/write in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem not even 5 minutes ago. I was trying to figure it out on the forums and googled it and all. After about 40 minutes of searching I decided to try and log out and log back in while the micro SD card and adapter were in the slot. Once logged in I tried to move my files in and it just worked. I heard somewhere in my searches that linux will try and protect the device if it's removed improperly to prevent data corruption, and the only way to fix it is to restart or log back in. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 2):

Following some googling, I found that blowing really hard into the card slot worked. Apperantly dusty cardslots can be responsible.

Comment: This did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to try to remount the device manually with explicitly given option "rw" and look what terminal says?

```
mount -o rw /dev/your_device /any_directory
```

Comment: The thing is, since i can only see it with the lock on, whatever i do i cannot chance the rights from read only to write/read.

Comment: You mean you have a device with hardware lock ability? I've heard such devices very expensive and supported very poor.

Comment: Maybe. You need to look for some unusual driver in the repositories.

Comment: here is the thing i am talking about:
http://www.amazon.fr/Kingston-m%C3%A9moire-microSDHC-adaptateur-Classe/dp/B003WIRFD2/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Comment: Did you check the kernel log?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: While connecting or disconnecting devices the kernel produce diagnostic messages that can give you more information about your problem. These messages you can view in the program 'System Log Viewer'. Look for the words related to your device (kingston,micro,sd) in the text of the logs.

Comment: You can also view the kernel log from the Terminal by running the [`dmesg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dmesg.1.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible data corruption**

Most probably there is an error in the filesystem of the microSD card, which causes Ubuntu to mount it as readonly (thus saving your data from further corruption).

To verify whether you have a case of data corruption, start

```
gnome-system-log
```

and check if you get any corruption messages as soon as you connect the microSD card.

What you should do in this case is to copy the files from the microSD card to your computer and format it again with the Disk Utility.
Then, copy the files back to the microSD card.

**Filesystem requires administrator access**

If you formatted the microSD card using the Disk Utility, you may have chosen the ext4 or other Linux filesystems. In this case, the user ID of the folder in the microSD card might be different from your own user ID.

To verify whether you have a case of wrong user ID, run

```
gksudo nautilus
```

and try to copy any file onto the microSD card. If the copy still fails, then you have the data corruption issue (thus, see above). If the copy works, then it is a permission issue with user IDs. You can use this Nautilus file manager to change the ownership of the folders/files on the microSD card. There is an option to `Take Ownership` in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem by **assigning a volume name to the Micro-SD card** (under Win). After this the problem disappeard under Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I suspect the last file I copied on the SD card got corrupted somehow (probably pulled the the card out too early).

I simply deleted the file using another PC (windows).
Re-inserted the card and all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking it with `fsck`
For example

```
umount /dev/sdb1
fsck /dev/sdb1
```

If the Dirty bit is set, it will ask you to remove it

```
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
```

You select 1 and then mount it again